# Get cell values from DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid

I have a DataGrid what is populated with data from a join.

```
private void GetTeamData()
{
    DataContext dc = new DataContext(connString);
    Table<Team> tblLag = dc.GetTable<Team>();
    Table<Division> tblDivision = dc.GetTable<Division>();

    var teams = from team in tblLag
                join division in tblDivision on team.Division equals division.Id
                select new
                {
                    name = team.TeamName,
                    beliggenhet = team.Location,
                    arena = team.Arena,
                    division = division.Name
                };

    dgTeams.ItemsSource = teams;
}
```

I want to get the data from the selected row and place it in different textboxes. After a lot of frustrating googling and trying i finaly find a solution what works:

```
private void ShowSelectedTeam(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    GetDivisionNames();
    dgTeams.SelectionUnit = DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow;
    Object selectedTeam = dgTeams.SelectedItem;

    List<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(selectedTeam.GetType().GetProperties());

    tbxTeam.Text = props[0].GetValue(selectedTeam, null).ToString();
    tbxBeliggenhet.Text = props[1].GetValue(selectedTeam, null).ToString();
    tbxArena.Text = props[2].GetValue(selectedTeam, null).ToString();
    cbxDivisions.Text = props[3].GetValue(selectedTeam, null).ToString();
}
```

The problem is that this is a pretty complicated way to do something what shouldn't need to be that difficult. I would be glad for suggestions for a more simplistic code.

Comment: Create a type that holds the name, beliggenhet , arena and division properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a type that holds the name, beliggenhet , arena and division properties:

```
public class YourType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Beliggenhet { get; set; }
    public string Arena { get; set; }
    public string Division { get; set; }
}
```

Set the `ItemsSource` to an `IEnumerable<YourType>`:

```
var teams = from team in tblLag
                join division in tblDivision on team.Division equals division.Id
                select new YourType
                {
                    Name = team.TeamName,
                    Beliggenhet = team.Location,
                    Arena = team.Arena,
                    Division = division.Name
                };
```

And cast the `SelectedItem` property to your type:

```
YourType selectedTeam = dgTeams.SelectedItem as YourType;
if (selectedTeam != null)
{
    tbxTeam.Text = selectedTeam.Name;
    tbxBeliggenhet.Text = selectedTeam.Beliggenhet;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it was clarifying. However, I'm a little reluctant to create a type just for this purpose. I'm not sure that will make the code less complicated overall. But I now know the options so I will consider it along the way.

Comment: Then you could use the `dynamic` keyword but then you lose compile-time safety. Why are you reluctant to create a type...!? Your current solution works but you think it's "complicated". Creating a type solves this.

Comment: Did you try my code? If you don't want to get runtime errors you should create a compile-time known type and try to cast to it using the `as` operator.

Comment: (Corrected comment from yesterday)
When googling compile-time safety I realize that's a good point. You say that the current solution works. But isn't it true, that in a situation when your suggested solution gives a compile time error, the code with a dynamic type will give a run-time error. My code might not give an error at all, but the code will not work as expected? With that in mind I think it might be best to create a type as you and ASh suggested. – PellePetimeter 12 hours ago

Comment: Yes I will create at type as you and ASh suggested. The reason I think that is wise is becaouse if there should be any incosostense between the Code that populates the grid and the code that gets data from the grid will cause compile time error, which is better than a run time error or just that the program stops working properly.

Answer (score 1):

it is so complicated to get selected item properties, because selected item has anonymous type.

create a type

```
public class TeamViewModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string beliggenhet { get; set; }
    public string arena { get; set; }
    public string division { get; set; }
}
```

create objects of that type when filling ItemsSource:

```
var teams = from team in tblLag
            join division in tblDivision on team.Division equals division.Id
            select new TeamViewModel
            {
                name = team.TeamName,
                beliggenhet = team.Location,
                arena = team.Arena,
                division = division.Name
            };
```

and you will be able to cast SelectedItem to concrete type and read properties without reflection:

```
private void ShowSelectedTeam(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    GetDivisionNames();
    dgTeams.SelectionUnit = DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow;
    var selectedTeam = dgTeams.SelectedItem as TeamViewModel;

    if (selectedTeam == null) return;

    tbxTeam.Text = selectedTeam.name;
    tbxBeliggenhet.Text = selectedTeam.beliggenhet;
    tbxArena.Text = selectedTeam.arena;
    cbxDivisions.Text = selectedTeam.division;
}
```

---

in case you still want to continue using anonymous types, you can use `dynamic` type to read values (only `ShowSelectedTeam` method changes):

```
private void ShowSelectedTeam(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    GetDivisionNames();
    dgTeams.SelectionUnit = DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow;
    dynamic selectedTeam = dgTeams.SelectedItem;

    if (selectedTeam == null) return;

    tbxTeam.Text = selectedTeam.name.ToString();
    tbxBeliggenhet.Text = selectedTeam.beliggenhet.ToString();
    tbxArena.Text = selectedTeam.arena.ToString();
    cbxDivisions.Text = selectedTeam.division.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it was clarifying. However, I'm a little reluctant to create a type just for this purpose. I'm not sure that will make the code less complicated overall. But I now know the options so I will consider it along the way.

Comment: @PellePetimeter, you are welcome. consider accepting one of the answers which you received

Comment: But when considering what mm8 pointed out about compile-time safety, I think it will be best to create a type, as you and mm8 first suggested.