# Get Datagrid cellvalue on cell click in WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid

When i click on a cell in my datagrid, it must save the value of the cell in a variable, so i can use it in a label on the next page.

Here is what i have now:

My DataGrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGridTilKonti" Grid.Row="1">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type"
                                    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderStyle}"
                                    Binding="{Binding kontoType}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kontonummer"
                                    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderStyle}"
                                    Binding="{Binding kontoID}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Saldo"
                                    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderStyle}"
                                    Binding="{Binding saldo}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseDown"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
        </DataGrid>
```

My click event, and just one of my countless attempts.

```
private void DataGridCell_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            //var grid = DataGridTilKonti as DataGrid;
            //var cellValue = grid.SelectedValue;
            //MainWindow.k.EnkeltKontoType = cellValue.ToString();

            MainWindow.k.EnkeltKontoType = 
            DataGridTilKonti.SelectedCells[0].ToString();



            NavigationService.Navigate(new EnkeltKontosTransaktioner());
        }
```

My DataGrid Style

```
        <!-- Style til DataGrid -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
            <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="Gray"/>
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="HeadersVisibility" Value="Column"/>
            <Setter Property="CanUserSortColumns" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="CanUserResizeColumns" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" Value="False"/>

            <Setter Property="SelectionUnit" Value="Cell"/>
            <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single"/>


            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 20 0 0"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <!-- Style til DataGridColumnHeaders -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" x:Key="DataGridHeaderStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseFontFamily}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 15 0"/>
        </Style>

        <!-- Der ligger en ekstra header under den som jeg ændrede på tidligere. Denne style gør den usynlig. -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Style>

        <!-- Style som fjerner den blå baggrundsfarve og sorte border når man trykker på en celle. -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

And the error i currently get:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: argument is out of range.

**Edit 1**: `SelectionUnit` set to `Cell` and `SelectionMode` set to `Single`

Updated error output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get cell values from DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51267586/get-cell-values-from-datagrid)

Comment: You can use `SelectedCells` property of your `DataGrid` like `grid.SelectedCells[0]`

Comment: @Aakanksha Now i get a new error: _argumentoutofrangeexception: argument is out of range_

Comment: @Martin Make sure you keep the DataGrid SelectionUnit property to Cell and SelectionMode property to Single

Comment: @Aakanksha Same error.

Comment: Can you update your code with what you have done so far

Comment: @Martin I just realized you don't need the selected value or selected cell of datagrid. You will get the cell value in your event handler itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the cell value of the `DataGrid` in the event handler like following.

```
    private void DataGridCell_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
        if (cell != null)
        {
            TextBlock tb = cell.Content as TextBlock;
            MainWindow.k.EnkeltKontoType = tb.Text;
            NavigationService.Navigate(new EnkeltKontosTransaktioner());
        }
    }
```